# Javascript Function Not Firing from C# Function ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using a asp:Repeater control while trying to develop a screen as shown below:
[Submit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KapIu.jpg)

When **ToolId** is entered on the TextChanged Event I am getting value for MaxToolLife stored as double. When an user enter values greater than the stored value for the field **ToolLife** I need to show Yes/No popup stating "The value entered is greater than existing value. Do you want to proceed?" on button submit or textchanged event.
Currently I am using the below code but I am not getting Javascript alert.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToDouble(txtToolLifeAchieved.Text) > maxToolLife)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Confirm", "javascript:Confirm();", true);

        if (hdnconfirm.Value=="Yes")
        {
            row["Pcs Produced"] = Convert.ToDouble(txtToolLifeAchieved.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            txtToolLifeAchieved.Text = "1";
            txtToolLifeAchieved.Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        row["Pcs Produced"] = Convert.ToDouble(txtToolLifeAchieved.Text);
    }
}
```

In place of Page.ClientScript I have also used "Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock" & /ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. Nothing is working as of now. I am unable to call the javascript function from code behind. Any immediate response would help a lot.

The confirm() is as shown below:

```js
function Confirm()
{ 
  var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT"); 
  confirm_value.type = "hidden"; 
  confirm_value.name = "confirm_value"; 
  if (confirm("The data already exists. Do you want to Overwrite data?")) 
  { 
    confirm_value.value = "Yes"; 
    document.getElementById('<%= hdnconfirm.ClientID %>').value = "Yes"; 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    confirm_value.value = "No"; 
    document.getElementById('<%= hdnconfirm.ClientID %>').value = "No";   
  }
  
  document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value); 
}
```

Comment: do you have a function called Confirm in the javascript? ... hmm `javascript:Confirm();` that looks wrong anyway ... what's the `javascript:` prefix supposed to do

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yes. When I am calling this in Page Load i am getting confirmation message. But When i call this inside button click this is not getting called.

Comment: Give us please the code of your ``Confirm`` method, thanks.

Comment: function Confirm() {
       
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("The data already exists. Do you want to Overwrite data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            document.getElementById('<%= hdnconfirm.ClientID %>').value = "Yes";
        }
        else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
            document.getElementById('<%= hdnconfirm.ClientID %>').value = "No";
        }document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value); }

Comment: Suggestion: you should edit the question and put this code there. That will make it readable. Also, is this the complete code of your `btnSubmit_Click()` function or is there something else? like redirect stmt?

Comment: @VivekAthalye: There are other code as well in btnSubmit_Click(). But those are not related to this. I just want to call a javascript function when a condition is true inside Subit function.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out rest of the code or alternatively, as @xxxmatco has shown, returning from function just after the script is registered? Because I'm suspecting that the other code in submit function is causing this behavior.

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer?

Comment: Yes, it worked but when i remove the update panel. If I keep this code within a update panel its not working. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Update panel is tricky, but try to take a look at the rendered html code, an according to that try to place your javascript code at the right place and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I will stick to your original code, and this is how your server method should look like:

```
// This is just to illustrate the limit
private const double MaxToolLife = 100;


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check the limit first
    if (Convert.ToDouble(txtToolLifeAchieved.Text) > MaxToolLife)
    {
        // If the hidden field is empty show the confirm
        // By default the hidden field is empty, it means that user just
        // pressed the submit button but not the confirmation dialog
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hdnconfirm.Value))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Confirm", "Confirm();", true);
            return;
        }

        // If the hidden field is not empty, this postback was made by the confirm
        // So check for the value of the hidden field
        if (hdnconfirm.Value == "Yes")
        {
            // Handle 'Yes'
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle 'No'
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The limit is not reached
    }
}
```

I omitted your specific code above. This is how the form looks like:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!-- Hidden field for the confirm result -->
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnconfirm" runat="server" />
    <!-- Text box for user input -->
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToolLifeAchieved" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <!-- Submit button -->
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</form>
```

Than right before the `form` tag in your page, place your javascript function, it must be place before the form tag, because calling `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` will append the script at the end of your `form` tag and that time your `Confirm()` method be defined. And this is your javascript method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        if (confirm("The data already exists. Do you want to Overwrite data?")) {
            document.getElementById('<%= hdnconfirm.ClientID %>').value = "Yes";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%= hdnconfirm.ClientID %>').value = "No";
        }

        // Post the form back to server using the '__EVENTTARGET' hidden field
        var form = document.getElementById("form1");

        // Create hidden field
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("name", "__EVENTTARGET");
        input.setAttribute("id", "__EVENTTARGET");
        input.setAttribute("value", '<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>');

        // Append input to the form element
        form.appendChild(input);

        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    } 
</script>
```

There is no need to create another hidden field for the confirmation result. Instead just right after the confirm you need to create hidden field with `name` set to `__EVENTTARGET`, and the value of that hidden field must be the name of the submit button, and than just call `submit` method on the form. This will case postback to the server, with the `hdnconfirm` set to **Yes** or **No** while your `btnSubmit_Click` method will be executed.